# Can't see how these equations connect.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am studing for a final and was reviewing an example but can't seem to remember how these equation transform into each other. Can someone explain what steps I am missing

Original problem
$$(x^2+y^2)dx + (x^2 - xy)dy=0$$
Substitution 
$$y=ux$$
$$dy=udx+xdu$$

problem
$$(x^2 + u^2x^2)dx + (x^2-ux^2)[udx+xdu] = 0$$
$$x^2(1 + u)dx + x^3(1-u)du = 0$$

I have tried distribution and just get this

$$x^2(1 + u)dx + x^2u(1-u)dx + x^3(1-u)du = 0$$

Why do I have and extra part in the middle.

Comment: Your first two terms have a common factor of $dx$.  Simply combine them (you'll have to do some rearranging of the $x$ and $u$ terms).

Comment: *headdesk* i have been staring at this for over an hour thanks. you mind putting that as an answer so I can mark this as answered and credit you.

Comment: Done.  And don't you just hate those headdesk moments? ;)

Comment: Only when I have one the night before an exam and I don't wake up until it is to late. I keep a pillow for headdeak moments now :) jk this has not happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first two terms have a common factor of $dx$. Simply combine them (you'll have to do some rearranging of the x and u terms) and all will be clear.